# Not able to get string out of pandas rather getting a datatype

Tags: python, pandas, string, types

```
read_file = pd.read_csv (r'settings.txt', header = None)
read_file.columns = ['username', 'password']
read_file.to_csv (r'settings.csv',index=None)

sett = pd.read_csv('settings.csv')

mailid= sett['username']
passw= sett['password']

print(mailid)
```

> I wanted to get only the string (i.e. asv@gmail.com) but this is what I am getting-
> [image: wrong-output]

> How do I change this to a string?

Comment: Can you include an example of what is in the .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print just the values of the mailid column as strings, you can use the .values attribute to access the underlying NumPy array and convert it to a regular Python list.

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv('settings.txt', header=None)
read_file.columns = ['username', 'password']
read_file.to_csv('settings.csv', index=None)

sett = pd.read_csv('settings.csv')

mailid = sett['username']
passw = sett['password']

print(mailid.values.tolist())
```

Comment: You can also use `mailid.tolist()` instead of `mailid.values.tolist()`. `values` converts the series into a Numpy array, then `tolist` converts the Numpy array to a python list, whereas using only `tolist` directly converts the series to a Python list, reducing the unnecessary overhead.